# How to upload aab to Internal App Sharing using gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to upload aab file to internal app sharing using gradle task. On google search option is there to upload using travis but is there any possibility to upload aab using gradle task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gradle Play Publisher plugin: 
https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher